# Using vue-multiselect as an input field with laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I need to select multiple users in a form. So I picked a vue component called [vue-multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/). But I do not know how can I receive the selected user's ids in the `$request` array.

This is how I am using the component:

```
<multiselect
   v-model="selected"
   :options="users"
   :multiple="true"
   track-by="id"
   @open="getUsers"
   :custom-label="customLabel"
   >
</multiselect>
```

I am binding the `options` to an array of objects called `users` and the selected user gets pushed to the `selected` prop.

The `getUsers` method performs an axios ajax call to fetch all the users to the `users` array.

I tried to insert a hidden input field in the form and v-modeled it to  the selected prop:

```
<input type="hidden" name="users" v-model="selected">
```

But when the form was submitted and I dd'd the request array in my Laravel controller:

```
dd(request()->all());
```

`request('users')` contained the value: `[object Object]`, which is definitely not what I expected.

How do I get the ID's of all the selected users?

Comment: Do you mean an empty object?

Comment: @Eisenheim use name attribute to get it in request.

Comment: @PassionInfinite Using name attribute doesn't solve the problem. It gives null when the request array is dumped.

Comment: @Eisenheim how you are submitting the form?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use computed field for your solution, example:

```
<multiselect
   v-model="selected"
   :options="users"
   :multiple="true"
   track-by="id"
   @open="getUsers"
   :custom-label="customLabel"
   >
</multiselect>
<input type="hidden" name="users" :value="selectedUsers">
```

and for example computed field:

```
computed: {
            selectedUsers: function () {
                let selectedUsers = [];
                this.selected.forEach((item) => {
                    selectedUsers.push(item.id);
                });
                return selectedUsers;
            }
        },
```

When you send your request you will see:

```
  'users' => string '114,159' (length=7)
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I assume the data `users` is an array of objects like this

```
let users = [
{id: 1, name: "john"},
{id: 2, name: "steve"}
];
```

Then this fixes your problem:

```
<multiselect 
  v-model="user" 
  name="userid"
  :options="types.map(type => type.id)" 
  :custom-label="opt => types.find(x => x.id == opt).name">
</multiselect>
```

The idea of this fix is, that the `options` property of multiselect will become a normal array of id's. Then `v-model` is a normal attribute and will be submitted normaly. The `:custom-label` will iterate for each select item through your userlist. So this is only a good idea if you have a selection with less then 100 entries I guess.

Its actually still in debate how this should be done at https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/issues/432.

However, it seems the best solution is, that the `options` property should not be a list of objects. This implies that `trackBy` should also not be used.